# '<' operator is reserved for future use when running the command choco install -y -s <path-download> "asio cunit eigen tinyxml-usestl tinyxml2 bullet"

Tags: ros

The '<' operator is reserved for future use.
+ CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : RedirectionNotSupported

this is the complete error

I was trying to download ros humble on windows

on this step:
download these packages from this GitHub repository.

asio.1.12.1.nupkg

bullet.3.17.nupkg

cunit.2.1.3.nupkg

eigen-3.3.4.nupkg

tinyxml-usestl.2.6.2.nupkg

tinyxml2.6.0.0.nupkg

Once these packages are downloaded, open an administrative shell and execute the following command:

choco install -y -s <PATH\TO\DOWNLOADS> asio cunit eigen tinyxml-usestl tinyxml2 bullet